# Step by step compilation of C Program

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Recently I was dealing with some problems in Compiler design. What I want is a tool which can do step by step compilation of the C Program. One which performs lexical analysis and gives an output file and then syntax analysis on this output file and so on until the final executable code is obtained. Is there such a tool or technique to do this? Of course I am familiar with lex and yacc. What I need is a single tool which can visually guide you through all the different phases of compilation, lexical analysis, syntax analysis, semantic analysis, intermediate code generation, code optimization and code generation.

Comment: Did you look at the toolbox provided by clang and llvm?

Comment: I need an automatic Spec-to-product-converter - where can I find one? - Joke aside: write your own using clang.

Comment: I think clang / llvm is what you want for optimization visualisation. For syntactical analysis - I think you'll hardly find a toll that does that for you.

Comment: That is a compiler (unless I misread).

Comment: Give a look at GCC too!

Comment: What is it for? Parsing is trivial and visualising any of the stages before AST is totally pointless. And most of the compilers provide tons of tools for visualising any imaginable intermediate code and derived structures (like CFGs, dominator trees, etc.). You can print IR before and after each pass in LLVM, for example, or you can dump various GIMPLE stages in GCC. You can even display CFGs with Graphviz using the standard LLVM passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are interested in knowing internals of GCC you can use `-fdump` option. It will create lots of files for every pass (mainly from middle end to backend, not sure about front end). This link might help you:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html